# Yii2 how to post record by field name

Tags: model, yii2, field

In Yii2 model, I can read records with field name, but how to post/update records by it?

Here is my fields(), which changes attribute name to field name.

```
public function fields()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'Id',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'tip' => 'Tip',
        'create_time' => 'CreateTime',
        'update_time' => 'UpdateTime'
    ];
}
```

I can post with 'Name', 'Tip', but I want post with 'name', 'tip'. Thanks!

Comment: This is unclear, you renamed your attributes and now you want to use original attribute names? So why you renamed them in first place?

Comment: Hi @Bizley, I don't want use original attribute. I want use field name both index/view and create/update.